# derivative of a linear mapping

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

What is the derivative of a linear mapping A: R^n -> R^n?  I assume it must be a tensor.

In particular, if I have a linear function of a vector x, A(x), what is DA(x)?

Comment: The derivative of a linear map is itself.

Comment: What is the best linear approximation to a linear function?

Answer (score 2):

You have $A(x+h) = A(x) + A(h)$, hence
$\|A(x+h)-A(x) - A(h) \| = 0$, from which we conclude that
$DA(x)(h) = Ah$, or, $DA(x) = A$.

Comment: Why the downvote?